# What is the problem named, 'img' attribute has no file associated with it.?

Tags: django, django-templates

My motive is to show the `product_image` in the `orderlist` template. The `ProductOrder` works well and it also stores the `product_image` url in the `img` in the database. But when tried to show the image in the template, it has shown an error. Where did the actual problem occur? Please give me a relevant solution.

***models.py:***

```
class Products(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="merchandise_product_related_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    
    product_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to = "1_products_img")



class ProductOrder(models.Model):

    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='UserOrderRelatedName',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

***views.py:***

***this works well,***

```
def Order(request, quick_view_id):

    OrderProduct = get_object_or_404(Products, pk=quick_view_id)

    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated:

        ProductOrder.objects.create(
            img = OrderProduct.product_image
        )
        return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)


def OrderList(request):
    AllOrder = ProductOrder.objects.all()
    context = {
        "AllOrder":AllOrder,
    }
    return render(request, "order_list.html", context)
```

***template:***

```
{% for order in AllOrder %}
<img style="width: 100px;" src="{{order.img.url}}">
{% endfor %}
```

***error:***

```
ValueError at /OrderList/
The 'img' attribute has no file associated with it.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/OrderList/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The 'img' attribute has no file associated with it.
Exception Location: D:\1_WebDevelopment\17_Ecomerce Website\ecomerce site\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py, line 40, in _require_file
Python Executable:  D:\1_WebDevelopment\17_Ecomerce Website\ecomerce site\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce site',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce site\\env',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce '
 'site\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 30 Jul 2022 13:52:11 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `product_image` or `img` does not have any image, you have to make an if condition that checks for the existence of the image, before rendering it.

For example, in your template:

```
{% for order in AllOrder %}
{% if order.img %}
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="{{order.img.url}}">
{% else %}
    <img style="width: 100px;" src="<some static image url>">
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this upload_to = "images" to class ProductOrder

models.py:

```
class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='UserOrderRelatedName',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to = "images")
```

templates:

```
{% for order in AllOrder %}
<img style="width: 100px;" src="{{order.img.url}}">
{% endfor %}
```

**or:**

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('media'))
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

templates:

```
<img src="/media/image1.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be arising during form submission. Maybe the actual file isn't being `POST`ed to the server so make sure you have `enctype=multipart/form-data` in your form where you have `method='post'`. Then on your view,the form responsible for submitting the data should have something like `form = YourForm(request.POST, request.FILES` or if you're not using a django form then have the image being picked from the request using `product_image = request.FILES.get('field_name')`